# How to Console multiple values without using template or Reactive Form

Tags: angular

This is the sample code. please help me with consoling multiple values without using any forms

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Text" #input>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Text" #input>
    
<div class="button" (click)="onClick(input.value)">
   <button class='btn btn-dark'>Submit</button>
</div>
```

TS

```
onClick(value: any) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add different local references to inputs and pass the values.

```
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Text" #input1>
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Text" #input2>
        
    <div class="button" (click)="onClick(input1.value, input2.value)">
       <button class='btn btn-dark'>Submit</button>
    </div>
    
    TS 
    
     onClick(value1: any,value2: any) {
        console.log(value1, value2);
     }
```

Comment: Please upvote if my answer helped you and mark it as solution if it resolved your issue. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

What form? `class="form-control"` is CSS class selector `.form-control`. If you wish to console log with a button, you can pass inputs values to the method as params. Though to reference the correct input each should have an unique name after hashtag `#`. We pass to method `onClick()` multiple params (the input's values), parse then as obj `{}` and we console log that obj.

Html

```html
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Text" #input1 />
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Text" #input2 />

<div class="button" (click)="onClick(input1.value, input2.value)">
  <button class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>
</div>
```

TS

```js
  onClick(input1: any, input2: any) {
    console.log({input1, input2});
  }
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jzoybi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: What if i'm using <option>  <select> How to console that?

Comment: Whatever you'd choose, it wouldn't matter if you just console log the data object that withholds the actual data. So why not just `console.log()` the original data in typescript method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator as a function parameter in this way on the TypeScript(TS) side, there is no change in the HTML side as pass the value to the function argument

Here on the HTML side, you can pass as many arguments you can pass

**HTML Code**

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Text" #input1 />
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Text" #input2 />
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Text" #input3 />

<div class="button" (click)="onClick(input1.value, input2.value, input3.value)">
  <button class="btn btn-dark">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**TypeScript Side**

```
onClick(...inputValues: any) {
    console.log(inputValues);
  }
```

so in the TS side, you need to add only 3 dots in the function arguments, 3 dots represent as spread operator.

You can get it as an array of values you have passed from the HTML to the TS side.

Hope it will help it to use the modern javascript features.